# Advice wanted on time to digital converters for speed of sound in fluids

Tags: fluid-mechanics, control-engineering, flow-control, electronics

I'm using the speed of sound to analyze the composition of aqueous solutions with sound velocities between around 1000 and 1400 meters per second. It's a process control application with continuous monitoring of a flowing fluid.

The plan is to have two piezoelectric transducers at one end of a pipe with a flat reflector plate at the other end, emit a sound wave from one transducer and detect its reflection with the other. It's done this way rather than with a transducer at each end of a tube so that the effect of the velocity of the fluid on the speed of sound is cancelled between the incident and reflected waves.

The chamber needs to be isothermal to close tolerances, and this limits its length to about 10 centimeters. I need to determine the range between the two speeds with the resolution of at least 20,000 points, ideally more. A time resolution of one nanosecond would be plenty.

I've looked at a number of chips that handle the interface between the transducers and the Arduino and I've identified three that offer the required performance. Those being the MSP430FR6047 and TCD1000 from Texas instruments and the TDC-GP22 from AMS. From the data sheets these all seem capable of doing the job. From what little I've been able to glean from forums, interfacing with the Arduino is quite complicated. These chips have a lot of functionality that I don't require because they're aimed at ultrasonic flow measurement and heat metering, but their temperature handling features are not sufficiently precise for my purposes and therefore I have to do that independently.

Does anyone have any advice about what chip they think would be most suitable, or if they have experienced another chip that would be better?

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear. I have the thermometric system sorted with a platinum resistance sensor and precision ADC. It is the TCD chip I'm not sure about. I'm thinking of using the TDC1000 but have not found any forum comments about using it with the Arduino and am not sure if there is a simpler or better tried solution.

Comment: @PatrickMitchell, I have used the TDC1000 + MSP430F5529. Texas instrument open sourced the integration software and is available publicly. Unfortunately they have discontinued the TDC1000 + MSP430F5529 development board. I recommend look at new TUSS44X0 platform from Texas instrument. They might already have example software developed in Energia (Arduino variant). I have heard about the AMS part, but have don't have hands on experience. Thus I am unable to comment. If you have question please come back. I can provide guidance.

Comment: Mahendra, thanks for the advice. I've looked at the data sheets for the TUSS44X0 system, and it certainly looks a better solution and also better supported. I'll start with that and sort an interface with the Arduino as necessary later. Thanks again.